Where do I get a "C" common wire on Utica Boiler UH15B-060K
Here are some pictures. The thermostat currently has 2 wired, red and white. There's 3rd wire available that's not connected to anything, and not connected to the boiler anywhere either.


And the diagram can be found here:
https://uticaboilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/240013259-REV-D-UH-IOM-15B-w-4200.pdf

There is no third thermostat wire in the picture. Are you sure it's there?

If you know how a transformer looks, find it.
From it you get 24 Volt and the C wire. (Pink and Brown)
Brown would be the C wire


the brown wire is the C

Traveler and Jasen - how do you know it's the brown and not the pink?  One of the yellow wires corresponds to one of the pink/brown wires, and the other pink/brown wire is C.  But it's not documented which way around.  Are you reading into the order of the test terminals above the plug?

@jay613 Brown is the common color code for C. Alternatively, measure the voltage between each and the COM terminal above it.
